The No test found issue between testng 6.9.9 and 6.9.10
When I using testng 6.9.9
with below code, the
package restAssured5;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoTest {
    @Test
    void simpleTest() {
        RestAssured.get("https://api.github.com/")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
    }


}

Run the test, display no tests were found.
change to version 6.9.10
run the same test, it's works,
so me question is any changes between these two version? testng 6.9.10 started support default method added @Test annotation and it can be detected by testng?
